# How can I create laravel 7 app with console?

Tags: laravel

with command like

```
laravel new  myapp
```

laravel 8 will be created.
But how can I to create laravel 7 app ?

Thanks!

Comment: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 myapp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works :)

`composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 7`